# Writing numbers as a sum of $2$'s and $3$'s

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Is there a way to count the number of ways a positive integer $n$, can be written as a sum of twos and threes? Are there any patterns? Re-arranging the twos and threes are distinct..(makes sense right?? or should they not be distinct)

I stumbled apon this question from a friend who wanted to test me, and quite frankly, i cant figure it out.

I've got another twist on the question that I may need some help with: What numbers have the number of ways for a positive integer $n$ to be written as a sum of $2$'s and $3$'s = $n$?

Comment: A variation on [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) will work, but might get tedious for larger numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I brute forced up to 16, but couldnt find any patterns, it gets quite tedious

Comment: Given that 6 can be written as a sum of three 2s or as two 3s, wouldn't this substitution be the key point to consider in recursively finding all pairs that would work?

Comment: hmm.. i didnt think of it that way, could you explain?

Comment: @Runik: What JB means is the following: Consider the number $38$.  How many different counts of three's could there be?  There could be $0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10$, or $12$ three's, each pair of three's "consuming" $6$ from the original $38$.  The remaining values could always be filled in by two's.  That's the basis of my answer below.

Comment: Depending on the number, the key is to be able to reduce it to a multiple of 6 so that then there are a couple of different combinations to note as a triple set of 2s would produce a 6 as would a double set of 3s. Thus, 8 and 9 for example each have 2 possibilities: 2+2+2+2=3+3+2 for 8 while 9 is 2+2+2+3=3+3+3. This would apply for 8,9,10,and 11. For 12, one could see this as a double of the 6 case and so one could use all 2s, partially use 2s or use no 2s for the 3 possibilities here. Integers of the form $6k+1$ are a bit special to handle differently of course but a pattern does exist.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for on the edit you created? I am referring to the "twist" on the original question.

Comment: @Rellek Basically if each order of 2s and 3s are distinct, what numbers would have s(n)=n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c_k$ be the number of ways that $k$ can be written as a sum of two's and three's.  If reorderings are not distinct, the problem is trivial.  By inspection, $c_0 = 1, c_1 = 0, c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = c_5 = 1$.  After that, the pattern repeats, but increasing by $1$ with each group of $6$.  That is to say,

$$
c_k = \lfloor k/6 \rfloor + c_{k \bmod 6}, \qquad k \geq 6
$$

If order matters, the problem is more complicated.  I'm not sure there's a closed-form solution for that.  I'll think about that some more.

ETA: I suspect there's a closed form.  It is specified by the recurrence relation

$$
c_k = c_{k-3} + c_{k-2}
$$

with $c_0 = 1, c_1 = 0, c_2 = 1$.  In other words, it's like the Fibonacci series, only reaching back one step further.  The justification for this recursion is that making any sum $k$ can be achieved only by first reaching either $k-3$ or $k-2$, and then adding three and two, respectively.  All sequences are distinct, so there is no recounting to worry about.

Working on the closed form now.

ETA 2: Ooh, it's messy.  Not sure this is what your friend had in mind.  The cubic corresponding to the recurrence, $r^3 - r - 1 = 0$, has some messy roots, two complex and one real.  The long-term behavior is (as you might expect) dominated by the real root, but even that value is messy:

$$
r_1 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}}
    \doteq 1.32472
$$

In the limit as $k$ grows without bound, $c_k \to \alpha_1 r_1^k$, where $\alpha_1$ is some constant.  It probably converges pretty quickly.

ETA 3: The other two roots, both complex, are given by

$$
r_2 = - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}
      - \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}}
$$

$$
r_3 = - \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}
      - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}}
$$

They're complex conjugates.  The expression for $c_k$ is of the form

$$
c_k = \alpha_1 r_1^k + \alpha_2 r_2^k + \alpha_3 r_3^k
$$

Given the initial values for $k = 0, 1, 2$, we know that

$$
\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = 1
$$
$$
\alpha_1 r_1 + \alpha_2 r_2 + \alpha_3 r_3 = 0
$$
$$
\alpha_1 r_1^2 + \alpha_2 r_2^2 + \alpha_3 r_3^2 = 1
$$

ETA 4: I did some figurings on the coefficients $\alpha_i$.  They're very messy.  Their values are approximately $\alpha_1 \doteq 0.41150, \alpha_2 \doteq 0.29425-0.13811i, \alpha_3 \doteq 0.29425+0.13811i$.

Comment: Hey Brian, you're absolutely right, i couldnt see that pattern, could you justify why that pattern exists, and will it persist?

Comment: Which pattern are you speaking of?

Comment: the complex Fibonacci that occured

Comment: This "reaching back one step further" Fibonacci sequence is also called a "skiponacci sequence"; with these initial conditions ($c_0=1$, $c_1=0$, and $c_2=1$), you get a third, linearly independent solution with respect to two others that are known and well-studied: the Perrin sequence and the Padovan sequence.  The growth rate is the so-called "plastic constant".

Comment: @mjqxxxx Im interested on this. I did some research, but I still cant figure out why this would persist throughout the sequence.

Comment: @Brian Any ideas?

Comment: I explained where the recurrence came from.  To solve an additive recurrence like that, you effectively pretend (for the moment) that the series is geometric as well, and solve for the possible geometric constant $r$.  In this case, this yields $r^3 = 1 + r$, or $r^3 - r - 1 = 0$.  This cubic has the three solutions described above.  This means that series of the form $r_i, r_i^2, r_i^3, r_i^4, \ldots$ satisfy the recurrence, for any of the roots $r_i$, *as well as* any linear combination of those series.

Answer (score 4):

I can help find a generating function, but judging from my first impressions this is not a simple problem.

Let us consider an infinite sum. We treat $x$ as a "dummy" variable, and consider only the coefficient in front of this.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s(n)x^n$$

Where $s(n)$ denotes the value of the amount of ways to create a number as a sum of 3's and 2's. We then find that we can reduce this by the properties of infinite geometric series. If you are a stickler for analysis, go ahead and assume $|x|<1$. We can recreate this sum as an infinite product (this concept of a generating function was a great insight by Euler when he did his initial work on the theory of partitions).

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty s(n)x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x^{2})(1-x^{3})}$$

If you expanded this series, the coefficient in front of $x^n$ would be the value that you are looking for, for some integer $n$.

The principles behind this are not too complicated but I realize that this probably doesn't make sense since I did not completely formalize this. However, expanding this series, I can give you some values. You said you used a brute force method on this, so, you can check with my values.

$s(2) = 1$ (obvious)
.
.
.
$s(16)$ = 3
.
.
.
$s(94)$ = 16

If you want to check values for yourself, check [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+1%2F%28%281-x%5E%282%29%29%281-x%5E%283%29%29%29+) out and expand the Taylor series.

Comment: For 16, I got 37..

Comment: Then you are asking for the composition (under restraints) for a given integer. This is the number theoretical term. I am assuming that order does not matter because this is what your original statement is asking. If you ask for the number of ways a number can be written as a sum of distinct specified number, since addition is commutative, I assumed order does not matter. Do you want me to calculate this for the compositions?

Comment: ah, Its okay, Brian walked me through that

Comment: @Runik: That's because he's not counting reorderings of the sum as distinct.  He's using the expression in the first part of my answer: $c_{94} = 15 + c_4 = 16$.

Comment: Yeah, he derived the expression you stated, thank you both of you

Comment: @Brian Tung  Hmm, I'm thinking about the twist I added, right now Ive only got 0 and 12

Comment: Just to add to this answer with a closed form for the partitions mentioned. Using partial fraction decomposition, you can show that the number of ways to decompose $n$ is $\frac{n+1}{6} + \frac{1}{4} ((-1)^n + 1) + \frac{u(n)}{3}$, where $u(n) = 1$ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, $u(n) = -1$ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $0$ if $n \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: @Runik It reminds me of the proof for the form of perfect numbers. Perhaps there is a general form for any integer satisfying this relation. Interesting!

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Yes that is a good point. I find it easier to throw it into Mathematica and have it just expand the series for me :P

Comment: @Runik: It's more consistent to assert $c_0 = 1$, not $0$.  The one way is the empty sequence.  Although it doesn't "look" like a way to add up to $0$, it is a (admittedly degenerate) sequence that works, unlike $1$, which no combination of two's and three's will add up to.

Comment: @Runik: Because the sequence quickly goes as $\alpha_1 r_1^k$ for $\alpha_1 \doteq 0.41150$ and $r_1 \doteq 1.32472$, the only term for which $c_k = k$ is $k = 12$.

Comment: @George: So $u(n) = [(n-1) \bmod 3]-1$, yes?

Comment: @BrianTung, yes.

Comment: @Brian Tung Did you get any other numbers than 12 and 1?

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams ^

Comment: @Runik: No: See my other comment.  Neither $0$ nor $1$ works, as $c_0 = 1$ but $c_1 = 0$.  Only $k = 12$ works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by just looking at how many $a$ and $b$ satisfy

$$2a + 3b = N$$

The quickest way I'd do this is by checking $N - 3b$ is even for increasingly larger $b$.

Comment: Yeah, from there you would simply do elementary combinatorics to figure out the number of ways they would be arranged. However, I have been told there is a pattern, or formula to do this

Answer (score 1):

**Without counting order** ($3+3+2$ and $3+2+3$ are counted once)

In this case the question is how many pair of non negative integers $(x,y)$ are there such that $2x+3y=N$
and in this case we have:

- If $N=2t$ then the number of solutions is $\left\lfloor\frac{t}{3} \right\rfloor$
- If $N=2t+1$ then the number of solutions is $\left\lfloor\frac{t-1}{3} \right\rfloor$

In general the number of non negative solutions of $ax+by=N$ is either $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{ab} \right\rfloor$ or $\left\lfloor\frac{N}{ab} \right\rfloor-1$

**Counting orders** ($3+3+2$ and $3+2+3$ are counted as twice, considered different )

I don't know any formulas for this but we can write it as a sum:
$$\sum_{2x+3y=N}{x+y\choose x} $$